# SSH into my Raspberry Pi 2@Optimum WiFi

Tags: wifi, ssh

I'm connected to `Optimum WiFi` with my `Raspberry Pi 2` and I'd like to be able to `SSH` into it from another network and even though it seems like I got public ip address assigned to my `wlan0` `WiPi` adapter I still cannot ssh in, I tried changing port from `22` to another that did *NOT* help.

`sshd` itself is running and listens on my newly selected port and I can ssh locally without any issues.

Comment: First, check that you have really a public address on RPi itself with ifconfig.

Comment: I dont know what Optimum WiFi is, but usually you need a permission on the router to pass through the port. And actually you can even be in subnet

Comment: @jaromrax I mean _NO_ disrespect by saying following: if you would've read my question you wouldn't write comment #1 as my question already contain answer and comment #2 is not useful at all.

Comment: What do you mean by "from another network"? Does the connection go through the internet?

Comment: @matthew yes, connection must be able to travel over internet.

Comment: @alexus - ok, then I am sorry for useless #2 and concerning #1, I have seen the wording *it seems*, because I have read the question. I think now you can cast your disrespect, as *this* comment is useless also from my point of view.

Comment: @jaromrax and that is exactly why i said "i mean no disrespect", certainly was not intend to hurt your feelings or anything like that, i do appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ssh reverse tunnel**:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ crontab -l | tail -1
@hourly     ssh -S alexus -O check X > /dev/null 2>&1 ; if [ $? != 0 ] ; then ssh -M -S alexus -fN -R2222:localhost:22 -p 443 X ; fi
pi@raspberrypi ~ $
```

req: `sshd` running on remote host, where you can ssh in and then ssh into your raspberry.

Answer (score 1):

To be able to connect to your pi from anywhere outside the local network, you will need to make sure that your router is set to port-forward.

To do so you will need to login to your router. If you're using Windows, open the command prompt and enter "ipconfig". Scroll up and find the ip address for the "Default Gateway", and enter this into your browser. If you're using Linux, the command is "ip addr".

It should then load a login page for your router, where you will need to enter the admin username and password. I cannot give you specific instructions after this part as each router has a different interface.

You will then need to search through the settings for an option that says "Port-Forwarding", which is usually a checkbox.

Restart your router and you should be able to connect from outside your local network.

Comment: `Optimum WiFi` is public hot spot that's provided by CableVision (cable company) and users do not have access to setup port-forwarding.

Comment: This page about the wifi doesn't mention anything about port-forwarding. https://www.optimum.net/internet/about-hotspots. Searching "port-forwarding optimum wifi" only mentions how to set up their router to port-forward. Are you sure?

Comment: am I sure? am I sure of what? As I said before users do _NOT_ have accesss to setup port-forwarding and you look at their page and also did not find anything...

Comment: My bad, I misread the comment. Anyway, "To be able to connect to your pi from anywhere outside the local network, you will need to make sure that your router is set to port-forward." If you can't port forward, you can't access from outside the network.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, you got an IP address in the 25.0.0.0/8 subnet with Optimum Wifi, which is not routed on the internet. See http://www.dslreports.com/forum/r26531911-Optimum-Wifi-Ip-addresses